# How did Black Widow survive while holding four Infinity Stones

Tags: plot-explanation, avengers-assemble

In *Avengers Assemble* Season 2 Episode 12 Black Widow controls 4 infinity stones (Reality, Space, Time and Mind). However she didn't collapse with all that power. Perhaps she should have disintegrated, being a mere human she cannot survive with such power let alone being able to control it. Captain America and Red Skull are more capable of doing so but did fail to possess even 1 infinity stone, which cause a near death experience to Super Humans. How was she able to do it without any special container (Gauntlet, etc).

Comment: You should consider, Avengers Assemble is not a part of MCU. so it may has some different roots on character development

Comment: Well it may not be MCU but it still doesn't justify the fact that captain america couldn't survive 1 stone yet widow controls 4 stones doesn't that seem ironic?

Comment: No, not at all. I can't recall the exact thing happens in that episode, but as I remember it, Widow has the perfect capability at the time to hold'em.

Comment: Yes, she did. But how is it justified?

Comment: Unless it was addressed in that episode, or others before or after, then the answer may be that 'It's not justified, and was a plot requirement'.